# React Fetch not working for one link but works for another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to use react to fetch api information (see below) but it is not returning any values but works when I use a different link. Not sure what the issue is with the second link. How do I make the second link work or is there a different method?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, []);

async function getData() {
  // await axios("https://randomuser.me/api")             // <----- this works
  await axios("https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds")    // <----- this does not work
  .then((response) => {
    setData(response.data);
    console.error("No Error fetching data: fds");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
    setError(error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
}
if (loading) return "Loading...";
if (error) return "Error!"; //dfdsaf
return ( <>
    {/* <img src={data.results[0].picture.medium} alt="random user" /> */}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
  </>
); }
```

Comment: Please describe in much greater detail what exactly isn't working. Hitting both those URLs directly I see data, so I suspect you aren't handling the response values correctly.

Comment: Something irrelevant to your question but just letting you know, you are using await to make your code synchronous, you don't need a "then" block. Do something like this instead: const wineData = await axios("https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds"); setData(wineData.data)

Comment: Hi, yea I am very new to react and fetching data. This was some online code I found and I just threw in a new url. How do I go about debugging and seeing the data that you see?

Comment: In the browser (Chrome) I just highlighted the URL, right clicked, and selected "Go to 'https:// .........'" and the JSON opens in a new window/tab. You could also drop a debugger on the `axios` line and inspect it, or use console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response structure is different and you may not need to use `.then` and `.catch` as you have already used `Async/Await`.

Here's a working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-waterfall-97tri?file=/src/App.js)

```html
<script type="text/babel">
// import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [randomUserData, setRandomUserData] = useState(null);
  const [randomUserLoading, setRandomUserLoading] = useState(true);
  const [randomUserError, setRandomUserError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getRandomUserData();
    getSampleApiData();
  }, []);

  async function getSampleApiData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios("https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds");
      setData(response.data);
      console.error("No Error fetching data: fds");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
      setError(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  async function getRandomUserData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios("https://randomuser.me/api");
      setRandomUserData(response.data);
      console.error("No Error fetching data: fds");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
      setRandomUserError(error);
    }
    setRandomUserLoading(false);
  }

  if (loading || randomUserLoading) return "Loading...";
  if (error || randomUserError) return "Error!";
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2, 1fr)",
        width: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(randomUserData, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default App;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You mentioned the response structure is different but where in the code did you account for it? It looks the same to me but that could just be that I dont know where to look

Comment: The response is different as in the internal response inside `response.data`. 

As mentioned by @rukshan, The API returns data as following. 


https://randomuser.me/api returns {"results":[{"gender"...

https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds -> returns [{"winery":"Maselva","wine"...

Answer (score 2):

The structures of the returning data from each APIs are different from each other.

```
https://randomuser.me/api -> returns {"results":[{"gender"...

https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds -> returns [{"winery":"Maselva","wine"...
```

So obviously just changing the URL won't work. You have to change the code accordingly to the structure of the returned data to access them properly.

Comment: Hi, yea I am very new to react and fetching data. This was some online code I found and I just threw in a new url. How do I go about debugging and seeing the data that you see and how do I adjust accordingly?

Comment: logging the response to the console before doing anything would make things easier -> `console.log(response)`

Comment: @YuanL In this scenario another option would be to visit the URLs in your web-browser. Most popular browsers have a special interactive JSON view in which you can inspect the structure.